# How to prove $a \leq c \Leftrightarrow [a\lor(b\land c)] \leq [(a\lor b)\land c]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

$(X, \leq)$ is a lattice (order).

For all $ a,b,c \in X$, can you prove
$$a \leq c \Leftrightarrow [a\lor(b\land c)] \leq [(a\lor b)\land c]?$$

As far as I have managed to do this:

(1)

Let: $[a\lor (b\land c)]\leq [(a\lor b)\land c]$

$a\leq [a\lor(b\land c)]\leq [(a\lor b)\land c] \leq c$

So: $a\leq c$

something that I found on my notes:
for $(a,b,c)\in X$

$a\leq a\lor b$, and $b\leq a\lor b$

$a\leq b, c\leq b \Rightarrow a\lor c\leq b$

$(a\land b)\leq a,a\land b\leq b$

$(a\leq b, a\leq c)\Rightarrow a\leq b\land c$
by definition.

Comment: What have you tried. If you show where you are having trouble, people will be in a better position to help you. We are not here to do the problem for you. Also, are there any examples in your notes or your textbook that resemble this problem?

Comment: I agree with @BernardMassé. In particular, which  direction of the $\iff$ is giving you trouble? One direction looks (to me) easier than the other.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I don't even know how to start, I haven't seen such examples before. It is the first time. So, I'm having trouble both.

Comment: I'd recommend starting with the definitions of $\lor$ and $\land$. They should give you information like (in the case of $\lor$) $x\leq x\lor y$ and $$ x\lor y\leq z\iff(x\leq z\text{ and }y\leq z)$$. Try to find some values for $x,y,z$ that will make this information (and the analogous information about $\land$) relevant to your problem.

Comment: I just added one side, I guess. I don't know if it is correct. What about the other?

Comment: By the way, a lattice for which the inequality on the right-hand side is always an equality whenever the inequality on the left-hand side is true is known as a modular lattice. So, have you seen modular lattices before, BugMeNot?

Comment: We have seen "lattices" only... I don't think we have seen it.
There is a note that I added to my question, which I have found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $a \le c$. Then, to show that $a \lor (b \land c) \le (a \lor b) \land c$, one must show four things:

1. $a \le a \lor b$
2. $a \le c$
3. $b \land c \le a \lor b$
4. $b \land c \le c$

The first inequality holds by the definition of $\lor$.

The second inequality holds by assumption.

The third inequality holds because $b \land c \le b \le a \lor b$ and $\le$ is transitive.

Finally, the third inequality holds by the definition of $\land$.

Since all four inequalities hold, one can conclude that $a \lor (b \land c) \le (a \lor b) \land c$.

Comment: thank you, if I have any questions I know where I should ask.